# Traspose Data in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am using PowerBI and I want to prepare a report that looks like the right side with a datasource as the left side, **How can I achieve that?**

*I am pulling JSON data from a web service and converting it into a table.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the Query Editor `Home=>Transform Data`

Then select `Home=>Advanced Editor` and paste the M code below into the window that opens.

Change the first few lines to reflect your own data source (and you may have to also edit some of the column references).

Read the code and comments to understand

- Group by ID
- Pivot each subgroup with no aggregation
- Combine the subtables

```
let

//change next lines to reflect your data source
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WykxR0lFyLUvNK1GIUIrVQRGIRBeIggoYYYgYY2gyRlYTCwA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t, Column2 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Column1", "ID"}}),

//Group by Table 2 (Events), then pivot each subtable
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Renamed Columns", {"ID"}, {
        {"Count", each Table.Pivot(_, List.Distinct([Column2]), "Column2","Column2")}
        }),

//expand the tables, then set the data types
    #"Expanded Count" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Count", List.Distinct(#"Renamed Columns"[Column2])),
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Count", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Expanded Count"), each {_, type text})),

//Replace Nulls with No, other entries with Yes    
    #"Yes/No" = Table.FromColumns(
            {typeIt[ID]} & 
            List.Accumulate(
                List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(typeIt),1),
                {},
                (state, current)=> state & 
                    {List.ReplaceMatchingItems(Table.Column(typeIt, current), 
                        {{null, "No"}} & List.Transform(typeIt[ID], each {_, "Yes"}))}),
            Table.ColumnNames(typeIt)
            ),
            
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Yes/No", List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Yes/No"), each {_, type text}))
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

***Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]